# is int8[] a valid data type in c++?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am trying to publish an array of int8 type. The following lines are used (not together).

```
ArbitraryLibrary::int8[] msg;
template<class int8[]>
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::int8[]>("Chatter", 1000);
```

I can't really test it right now, but will this allow me to publish an array of int8 type messages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67307/is-int8%5B%5D-a-valid-data-type-in-c++?/) by [Bholms](https://answers.ros.org/users/5097/bholms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2013-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code example won't work, because topics always have a message type (not an array of primitives). So there are two options:

1. Use the `std_msgs/Int8MultiArray`; this is the message definition:

   ```
    # Please look at the MultiArrayLayout message definition for
    # documentation on all multiarrays.

    MultiArrayLayout  layout        # specification of data layout
    int8[]            data          # array of data
   ```

   Then instantiate your publisher like this:

   ```
    ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Int8MultiArray>("Chatter", 1000);
   ```
2. Alternatively, define your own message type (`my_pkg/Int8Array`):

   ```
    int8[] data
   ```

   Then instantiate your publisher like this:

   ```
    ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<my_pkg::Int8Array>("Chatter", 1000);
   ```

It's probably better to define your own message type, because message types should always have a semantic meaning. If the topic type is "array of integers", this doesn't tell the subscriber how the data should be interpreted (range measurements in meters? encoder readings? temperatures?). Depends on the circumstances, though.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-07-15**:
hmm... In regards to your last comment, I would have thought the exact opposite. I like the message types simple and the topic names semantic. Might be a good topic for a best practice question...

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-07-15**:
Oh, there have been plenty of best practice discussions around that (e.g., [this ros-users thread](https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros/mailman/?_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=91558&action=ListThreads&mailman_id=20) ).

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-07-15**:
Of course, the design decision depends on the specific case. If you want to represent a 6D pose, `float[7]` would be too generic, `geometry_msgs/PoseStamped` is just right, and `my_pkg/PathPlanningTargetPose` would be too specific.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

int8 is a [valid primative](http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg#Fields)

It is not a [message defined in std_msgs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/std_msgs) (You'll find Int8 is though.  )

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1